# Extract information for maximum number of a duplicated cell from adjacent cell

Tags: excel, xls

I am new to excel automation. 
I have an excel of 2 columns(A-ID & B-Rev)
A column contains ID but few are duplicated (Example ID 65978 is used 5 times). However, corresponding Rev is unique for an ID.
I need to find out unique ID for which corresponding Rev is maximum .
How can I automate this using Formula?

Id  -----|   Rev

65978   |2

65978   |5

65978   |9

65978   |7

65978   |8

65979   |4

65980   |2

65980   |3

65980   |4

65980       |5

65980       |6

65983   |2

65983   |3

65984   |1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a formular solution. You can get this also with macro/vba and pivot.

1. Sort your table A1:B16 on column "rev" with heighest number on top
2. Assuming the content of your table starts at A2, paste following formular in C2: `=INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF(C1:$C$1, $A$2:$A$20),0,0), 0))`
3. Paste next formular in C2: `=INDEX($A$2:$B$20, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF(C1:$C$1, $A$2:$A$20),0,0), 0),2)`
4. Select cells C1:D16 and press Ctrl-u to paste the formular down

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: @Biplab: Thank's for the hint. I updated the answer and put commas in the formulars.

Comment: Commas or semicolons on formulas depend on regional settings of computer user

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pivot table. drag the IDs to the Rows and for the values the max of Rev.

Comment: I am sorry.
I dont know how to use Pivot table as very new.

Comment: Select all your data and on the insert robin select inesrt pivot table on a new sheet. now drag the IDs to the rows (donwn left quar) and drag the Rev to Values (down right quar) . Right click it and change the value field setting from count to max.